# Remove elements from a list by iterating via stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to remove some elements from my list of objects based on certain conditions.
Can I do it with Java 8 streams?

```
public static void doAction(List<Hunt> list) {
    for (ListIterator<Hunt> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Hunt h = iter.next();
        if (h.getTokens().contains("INC")) {
            String[] tags = h.getTokens().split(";");
            for (String tag : tags) {
                if (tag.contains("INC")) {
                    String value = tag.substring(tag.length() - 1);
                    if ("N".equals(value)) {
                        if (flag) {
                            if (!h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue())) {
                                iter.remove();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (!h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue)) {
                                iter.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: list.removeIf(predicate); A Stream will never alter the collection it's created from.

Comment: Try using filter and passing the predicate[1] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Comment: You can simplify the two tests to one using a regex: `tag.matches(".*INC.*N")` checks if it contains `INC` and ends with `N`. Alternatively, `tag.contains("INC") && tag.charAt(tag.length() - 1) == 'N'` would also avoid an extra level of nesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it with stream by using `removeIf` and some condition :

```
list.removeIf(h -> h.getTokens().contains("INC") &&
        Arrays.stream(h.getTokens().split(";"))
                .filter(tag -> tag.contains("INC"))
                .map(tag -> tag.substring(tag.length() - 1))
                .filter("N"::equals)
                .anyMatch(v ->
                        (flag && !h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue())) ||
                                (!flag && !h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue()))));
```

Or you can separated the condition in a separated method, for example :

```
static void doAction(List<Hunt> list) {
    list.removeIf(MyClass::isCorrect);
}

private static boolean isCorrect(Hunt h) {
    return h.getTokens().contains("INC") &&
            Arrays.stream(h.getTokens().split(";"))
                    .filter(tag -> tag.contains("INC"))
                    .map(tag -> tag.substring(tag.length() - 1))
                    .filter("N"::equals)
                    .anyMatch(v ->
                            (flag && !h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue())) ||
                            (!flag && !h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue())));
}
```

---

Or as [**@Tom Hawtin - tackline**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800754/remove-elements-from-a-list-by-iterating-via-stream-java-8/59801040?noredirect=1#comment105752964_59801040) suggest, you can use :

```
static void doAction(List<Hunt> list) {
    list.removeIf(h -> h.getTokens().contains("INC") &&
            Arrays.stream(h.getTokens().split(";"))
                    .anyMatch(tag -> tag.contains("INC") && tag.endsWith("N")
                            && !(flag ? h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue())
                            : h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue()))));
}
```

Comment: I think you can simplify the filter-map-filter-anyMatch with `.anyMatch(tag -> tag.contains("INC") && tag.endsWith("N")  && !(flag ? h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue()) : h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue()))`. (Your `flag` doesn't match the original question.)

Comment: Thank you @TomHawtin-tackline I agree, I fix it

Answer (score 1):

IMO stream API wont help you in this case! And this style of code is more readable in compared with stream based version. however I think you can make improvement by changing a bit.

- Remove temporary variables such as `String[] tags = h.getTokens().split(";");` and `String value = tag.substring(tag.length() - 1);`
- Combine some conditions with together.
- Use `tag.charAt(tag.length() - 1)` instead of `tag.substring(tag.length() - 1);`

  ```
  public static void doAction(List<Hunt> list) {
     for (ListIterator<Hunt> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Hunt h = iter.next();
        if (h.getTokens().contains("INC")) {
           for (String tag : h.getTokens().split(";")) {
                if (tag.contains("INC") && tag.charAt(tag.length() - 1) == 'N') {
                   if (flag) {
                       if (!h.getPropertyA().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyAValue())) {
                          iter.remove();
                       }
                   } else {
                       if (!h.getPropertyB().equals(anotherObject.getPropertyBValue)) {
                          iter.remove();
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        }
     }
  }
  ```